# Finding the average of a periodic function over all time

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, average, periodic-functions

Let's say I've a function $y:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ that is periodic in $T$. If I want to know that average of the function over the defined region I need to find:

$$L:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n-0}\int_0^ny(t)dt$$

But I can also write that as:

$$L=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Ty(t)dt$$

> How can I prove that that is true?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You will have more chances to get assistance if you show what you have done so far.

Comment: I've no idea where to start

Answer (score 1):

you can write 
$$
\frac 1n \int_0^n y(t) dt  = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{ \left[\frac{n}{T} \right] } \int_{(k-1)T}^{kT} y(t) dt + \frac{1}{n} \int_{ T [n/T] }^n y(t) dt,
$$
where $[\cdot]$ stands for the integer part. All integrals in the sum are equal to $\int_0^T y(t) dt$ in view of peridicity and you have $[n/T]$ of them.
So we end up with
$$
\frac 1n \int_0^n y(t) dt = \frac 1n [n/T] \int_0^T y(t) dt + \frac{1}{n} \int_{ T [n/T] }^n y(t) dt.
$$

The last item above converges to 0, and $\frac{1}{n}[n/T]$ converges to $1/T$.

Comment: How do I know that I can write the first (equation)line of your answer?

Comment: it's the additivity of integral, nothing special; just a partition of  the interval $[0,n]$.